# VSO Migration: Unable to retrieve information for security object $PROJECT:vstfs:///

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I have installed OpsHub and trying to migrate the source code from VSTF2013 to VSO. After selecting the TFS Endpoint and VSO Endpoint, clicking on Next. When trying to load the projects to be migrated I am getting this error, `"TF50608: Unable to retrieve information for security object $PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/faedd6e7-e2bc-4f91-917f-3823c951e71b, it does not exist."`

When I select some other `TPCs` in the same `VSTF` server, I am able to load the projects in VSTF. Could not understand this error code if this is related to security configuration at TPC level or OpsHub is trying to load some project which is does not exist?

I have done some search on this error code TF50608, looks like this issue can occur if any Team Project is deleted and created with the same name. I am able to connect to TPC and load the projects using TFS Administration Tool (http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/) but OpsHub fails to load the projects.

Is there any work around to skip this error and continue with the selection of the Team Project?

Comment: can you use VERSION 1.0.1.005, in which this issue is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have verified it is a defect. It will be resolved in the next build coming out soon.
use VERSION 1.0.1.005, in which this issue is resolved